# Django: how to get model field is ManyToManyField or not

Tags: python, django

I want to get model attribute is ManyToManyField or not

Expected Output

suppose attribute is name

is this attribute ManyToManyField or not output in True and False

```
qry = model.objects.get(id=1)
qry.name
```

is these attribute ManyToManyField or not how I check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ManyToMany field in the instance is a special kind of the model manager so you can test it with the `isinstance()` function:

```
from django.db.models import Manager
is_many_to_many = isinstance(qty.name, Manager)
```